# Domino Web SSO : Invalid username or password was specified

Tags: xpages, single-sign-on, lotus-domino

I configured a Web sso for my domino server.  When I opened the .xsp page, a yellow background HTML log-in form appeared and asked me to type my user name and password.

But after I entered the correct user name and password(I'm sure they are correct), this yellow log-in form asked me to type over and over again!

I was totally confused. Anybody knows what's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify what kind of SSO you are using (LTPA Websphere Token or any other kind of 3rd party products). Please specify what you have done with your user account: did you set the internet password in your person document? Check the settings for internet name and password (variety with less security or fewer name variation with higher security).

Comment: Also, make sure your login page is set to allow public access users. It is easy to forget this.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I mistakenly used IP address as my hostname. That's why the login prompt reappeared over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the hostname specified for the ltpa token in the SSO document matches the hostname you're using to access your XPage. If they don't match, the login prompt will reappear with no error message.

Comment: Thank you so much Per. I  mistakenly used IP address as my hostname. That's why the login prompt reappeared over and over again.

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember to accept the answer as a valid answer