# XPage: Unable to Login

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Very strange issue I am facing from past few days. I am just able to login to any application on my domino server using "Mozilla Firefox". If I use any other browser (Chrome, IE), it just stays on the login page with absolutely no information, everytime I login in it again shows back the login page with no error message at all. Its quite strange since its working perfectly fine on Firefox.

I am not sure, but I somehow feel that it has something to do with the configuration. Would really appreciate if someone can guide me here.

Edit 2: 
Selecting **Single Server**, does work, that was the simplest solution; as of now we do not need "Multiple Server".

However, we do not use any other "Internet Sites", I tried to remove the organization field, however, that lead me to "An R5 web SSO configuration already exists", which in turn lead me to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS8Uc.jpg). However, I am able to move further here with "Multiple Servers".

Edit 1: Based on the answers, here are the things I tried. Please find below the snapshot of each of it for better understanding..

**LTPA Token Configuration**

[image: LTPA Token Configuration]

**Server Configuration for LTPA Token**

[image: Server Configuration for LTPA Token]

**Network tab - before login**

[image: Network tab - before login]

**Network tab - after login**

[image: Network tab - after login]

Console shows nothing before or after login, neither does the server log files. Also, I am able to access the names.nsf database with absolutely no problem. Lastly, I try to access a database with no anonymous access and hence get redirected to the login page (however, as question mentions, it just stays in loop)

Comment: Are you using the exact same host name/URL in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same.

Comment: Its kind of a very strange problem, I can provide a teamviewer access if required..

Comment: Chrome and IE share the same properties at the OS level. Try to reset settings in IE.

Comment: I did reset it once, infact I uninstalled chrome and installed it again, with no  success, let me try with IE once and give the update..

Comment: Just did a reset for IE, still nothing..it just doesn't login..

Comment: You know, that Login only works, if you use the fully qualified Hostname as URL, if SSO is configured, do you? http://myserver/mail/mymail.nsf is DIFFERENT from http://myserver.mydomain.com/mail/mymail.nsf and will NOT work, if SSO is enabled

Comment: The reason I didn't dig deep is because it does work on Firefox so it seemed quite unlikely because of that..I usually access using the first way..let me check it again and update the same..

Comment: From the pictures it looks like you are accessing kraftiny.kraftiny.com but your LTPA token is for kraftiny.com. This explains the reloading of the login page. See this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570638/domino-web-sso-invalid-username-or-password-was-specified

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your point. Yes, after @Torsten suggestion I use kraftiny.kraftiny.com/database.nsf (instead on kraftiny/database.nsf), however, LTPA token just asks for domain name, right? I am sorry, I didn't get it clearly. What exactly should I change now to get started?

Comment: LTPA token is for kraftiny.com so use that as hostname - else logon will fail  (with a reload of the login page as the result)

Comment: Tried that after your comment..even that reloads the page.

Comment: @Per: It is totally ok to use the complete hostname, that is the reason for using LTPAToken: One token can log you in to test.kraftiny.com and test2.kraftiny.com and kraftiny.kraftiny.com, but not "test.test.kraftiny.com"

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: Your welcome. By the way: As comments to my answer showed: In fact Chintan did NOT use the same URL, as he did not realize the difference between using only common name and fully qualified name in URL. Thats why I asked "more concretely", because I know, that most admins would tell you "yes", if you asked if testserver.domain.com/names.nsf is the same url as testserver/names.nsf

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you may need to provide a little more information.

Are you doing a "normal" login using domcfg and a "...&login" url? Or are you trying to open a design element in a database that has no access to "anonymous" and thus redirects to the login?

You can easily check that "standard" login by opening the url: `http://yourserver.com/names.nsf?login`. Does it behave differently in the browsers? If not then your server setup etc. is Ok. Then you have to look at the solution that tries to log you in.

Your first place to check is in the browser's console. Are there any errors in there? E.g. some client side Javascript that stops running? Check the network tab when you inspect the console/developer tools. Does it send the right requests?

Another step is to check the console/log files on the server. If you have grown your own solution then you may want to add some simple print statements to prove that it sends what you think.

Finally, you can use a network sniffer (like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org)) to see exactly what is sent between your browser and the server.

/John

Answer (score 1):

A login- page that reloads itself after every login without a message like "Wrong username or password" or similar normally happens if the session authentication for the server is configured as `Multiple Servers (SSO)` (Found in Server document on `Internet protocols-Domino Web Server`, if Internet Sites are Disabled or in `Internet Site document`, if they are enabled).

In that case an LTPAToken has to be configured as well, and this token has to have a configured domain name. Whenever you try to access a server with SSO enabled using a hostname without domain or with a different domain, then exactly this will happen: Login- Page reappears after every try to login.

Example:

if the servername is `myserver` with ip `10.10.10.1` and the LTPAToken is configured for ".mydomain.com", then the only valid URL for login is:

**hxxp://myserver.mydomain.com**

Trying **hxxp://myserver** or **hxxp://10.10.10.1** will result in exactly the described behaviour.

***It is important to know, where to look for the "right" SSO- Configuration document.***

If the server is configured to use "Internet Site documents" (`Server- document, Basics- Tab, Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents` enabled) , then the SSO- document needs the field "Organization" to be filled. In that case you will find it in the `Web\Internet Sites`- View of the domino directory.

If Internet Sites are disabled, then the Field "Organization" has to be empty. In that case you find the SSO- document in the `Web\Configurations` view.

Comment: Agree - and that's why I asked: "Are you using the exact same host name/URL in all browsers?". Chintan has confirmed that the host name/URL is the same.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for the answer, however, even after doing the same it didn't work. It again works well in firefox and just doesnt work in Chrome and IE. I can provide snapshots with "network tab" (developers tool), my console, my LTPAToken settings and anything if required..please let me know..

Comment: Host name/URL is same in all browsers, however, after changing it to "hxxp://myserver.mydomain.com", it stops working in firefox too (with login loop)

Comment: Have just updated the question, probably it helps in understanding the problem further. Please let me know if I need to append anything further to make my question clear. Thanks again.

Comment: please tell us exactly the URL that you use in your browser, the screenshots look OK, but something has to be wrong...

Comment: I use kraftiny.kraftiny.com/database.nsf (instead on kraftiny/database.nsf which I used before this answer), however, now as mentioned, even the firefox doesn't work. I am trying to follow @Per, probably, he knows my mistake (he has commented in the question)

Comment: First: Do you use "Internet Sites"? If not then there should not be an "Organization" in your LTPAToken. Second: Do you have more then one server? If not: Use "Single Server" for session authentication, then this problem will be gone instantly...

Comment: Well, definitely, the "Single Server", does work, that was the simplest solution, as of now we do not need "Multiple Server". However, we do not use any other "Internet Sites", I tried to remove the organization field, however, that lead me to "An R5 web SSO configuration already exists", which in turn lead me to "http://heidloff.net/nh/home.nsf/article.xsp?id=21.05.2012084808NHE9Z5.htm". However, I am able to move further here with "Multiple Servers". (Just updated the question accordingly).

Comment: Then you have 2 documents and edited the wrong one. Check "Web - Web Configurations" and there the first document "* - Web SSO Configurations" in your domino directory...